# ADO Error Code 0x Issue in Crystal Reports with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

I'm facing an issue in Crystal Reports while using a SQL statement:

```
select Top 1 openingbalance,dated
FROM ledgerbalance 
where accounttitle= '{?tran}' and  dated='{?dateb}'
order by ledgeridnew asc, dated desc;
```

I'm facing error in the `WHERE` clause.

[image]

Comment: I would try temporarily replacing the `{?}` parameters with hardwired values to see if they are the reason for the syntax error. Maybe also the `dated` field needs to be in a specific date format and the parameter you supplied did not conform to that.

Comment: Given that the parameters have not been supplied, I would say that this question needs an [mcve] to be answerable.